# Forcing Numeric Keyboard in Internet Explorer on Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

Hi I am developing a Jquery Mobile website for **Windows Phone 7.5**, have an input field as such:

```
<input type="number" />
```

which unfortunately shows an alpha keyboard.

Is there any way to force a numeric keyboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found that using:

```
<input type="tel">
```

worked best for me. For windows phone (tested on 8.1) the pattern trick does not work (even though it will for iOS and possibly android). I didn't want to use type="number" since on the html that brings up the arrows to select the number in most browsers and I was doing this for a zip code so that doesn't make sense. I haven't seen any downside for using the 'tel' type on the html side.

I know this is an old question but since there aren't a lot of WP answers out there it may help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the input type to:

- type="email"
- type="url"
- type="tel"

Or (Ref: [Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html))

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*"></input>
```

Related:

- [Is there a numeric keypad for jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619459/is-there-a-numeric-keypad-for-jquery-mobile)

Answer (score 1):

To force a numeric keyboard, use the following:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]" />
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: I don't think this works on Internet Explorer on Windows Phone.